# Multiple select Form Value String

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need a multiple select form, like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 
<form action="" method="get">
<p>
  <select class="multiple normal-selectbox" id="RW" name="RW" multiple="multiple">
<option  value="N" ><span class="input-group"><strong>Region Nord</strong></span></option>
   
    <option  value="HAM" ><span class="input-group">Hamburg</span></option>
    <option  value="HAJ" ><span class="input-group">Hannover</span></option>
    <option  value="BRE" ><span class="input-group">Bremen</span></option>
   
  </select>
<div class="form-group submit f0 " data-fid="f0" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="progress" style="display: none; z-index: -1; position: absolute;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="z-index: 1;">
    GO
  </button>
  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After submit it hast to get Values as String in URL it get it so:

...?RW=N&RW=HAM&RW=HAJ&RW=BRE

But I need it so:

Rw=HAMxHAJxBRE ...

i find this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
            $("#results").append(field.name + "x" + field.value + " ");
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
</form>

<button>Serialize form values</button>

<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't Get Values to URL

Do you have any idea to solve my problem?

Regards

Hello friends thank you for your help, I made some code the result is what I want to string in to URL i don't know why

hier is the Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
            $("#results").append("" + field.value+"x");
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="get">
  <label>
  <select name="RW" multiple class="multiple normal-selectbox" id="RW">
    <!--<option value="-" selected="selected" >alle Abflugh&auml;fen</option>-->
    <optgroup label="Norden">
    <option  value="N" ><span class="input-group">Region Nord</span></option>
    <option  value="HAM" ><span class="input-group">Hamburg</span></option>
    <option  value="HAJ" selected ><span class="input-group">Hannover</span></option>
    <option  value="BRE" ><span class="input-group">Bremen</span></option>
   
  </select>
  </label>
</form>
<button>Serialize form values</button>

<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

also the string should be RW="results"

Comment: _"but it dosent GEt Values to URL"_ - well of course it doesn't, you are just writing text into a div element ... Assemble the correct URL including the GET parameters in a string variable first, and then assign that to `window.location.href`

Comment: I don't know about the JS but to get multiple values of `RW` you'll need the `select` as an array: `name="RW[]"`

Comment: the partameter should be exactly like this Rw=HAMxHAJxBRE seprate with a small x i tried name="RW[] but it dosent work

Comment: AbraCadver,  could you please let me know how to select an array for name="RW[]" i don get it or somebody els

Comment: i get this %5B%5D=HAM&fruits%5B%5D=HAJ result it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using PHP on the server-side - as implied by the PHP tag on this post, PHP should show this as an Array automatically. For an ordinary field, `$_REQUEST['RW']` would be a single value (e.g., "HAM") for a multiple select it will be an array (e.g., `["HAM","HAJ"]`). Just let PHP do the work for you and don't try to decode the URL yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but still it GET: ...index.php?RW%5B=HAM&RW%5B=HAJ it should be ...index.php?Rw=HAMxHAJxBRE!...

Comment: What language are you using on the server?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean what language?

Comment: All scripts on a server need are written in some language. PHP is one of the most popular and you have tagged the question for PHP. Other possibilities include Python, Perl, Java and there are many others.

Comment: OK also PHP, but in this case I prefer to use JavaScript do you have any idea?

Comment: PHP is on the server. JavaScript is on the client (aka the browser). You use JavaScript to manage the user experience but the data is getting processed by PHP. JavaScript has no access to the database.

Comment: The Form has no Database its just for get Strings in to URL but if you have an idea with PHP let me know pleas :-)

Comment: Are you using PHP or not?

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up. If you are using PHP then you should NOT be parsing the GET URL directly. Let PHP do the work for you.

Comment: I tried to do it with PHP but it didn't work correctly or i couldn't to get it how does it work, so I decided to use JavaScript

Comment: Then I don't think I can help any more here. Find a tutorial about using PHP to process a form. JavaScript is an incredibly useful tool but under most circumstances you need to have something "server side" to process the data.